# Real Player uses 100% CPU

Tags: windows-7, video, realplayer

When I click on "my library", then "all media", real player freezes and takes 100% cpu.

Any workaround?

Comment: Ah, I've found the source of the problem. Realplayer is what is called in the technical term: crapware.

Comment: I remember when RealPlayer was *the* player to have...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, you didn't provide us much information. But the best thing to do is to do a complete uninstall <strike>and reinstall</strike>.

My next suggestion is to avoid RealPlayer like the plague.

Try [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) instead.

Comment: yep,realplayer isn't used much these days,it's too bloated

Comment: RealPlayer is just a piece of *Insert proper word here* . And If I don't made a mistake, he now come with spyware... But I'm not sure on this point.

Comment: The plague can be cured with relative ease these days - the memories of realplayer still haunt me 10 years later. Avoid.

Comment: So just omit the "and reinstall" part :-)

Comment: @stefan How's that? :)

Comment: That's more like it :)

Answer (score 2):

Workaround:

1) Start > Control Panel > Add/Remove Programs

2) Select RealPlayer

3) Click "Remove"

Comment: No votes for humor? Sheesh!

Comment: This isn't humour, it's actually good advice!